# Add string to h5 file

Tags: python, string, numpy, pytables

I have the following code:

```
import tables
import numpy as np

filename = "file.h5"

x = np.random.random(150)
z = np.random.random(150)
mystr = " " * 160

f = tables.open_file(filename, mode="w")
hds = f.create_carray(f.root, "x", obj=x, 
                      filters=tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib'))
hds = f.create_carray(f.root, "z", obj=z, 
                      filters=tables.Filters(complevel=5, complib='zlib'))                
f.close()
```

I would like to add a string to my file with the length of 160. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `h5py` you can store numpy arrays containing strings (or just one) as a dataset.  Or you can store a string as an attribute of either a group or a dataset.

```
 http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/strings.html
```

It can be as simple as:

```
dset.attrs["title"] = "Hello"
```

I haven't used `tables`, but it's got to have access to these attributes as well.  Isn't there something in the documentation?

The file object itself has a `.attrs` dictionary as well.

Answer (score 0):

Storing string type data in H5 is somewhat tricky. It is a common problem for the first time H5 user in Python. The data type must be presented clearly before putting into an H5 dataset (i.e., whether if it is a string, integer, or float). As for string data type, you need to specify it as a variable. For example, *dt = h5py.string_dtype()*.

Below is an example to put a string in a H5 file.

```
import h5py
data = 'value in string'
f= h5py.File('./fname.h5','w')
try:
    dt = h5py.string_dtype()
    f.create_dataset('str_data', data=data, dtype=dt)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Also, for your reference, to check if the data is stored correctly, just use the following code.

```
f= h5py.File('./fname.h5','r')
try:
    print(f.keys())
    print(f['str_data'][()])
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    f.close()
```

For further reference, please read the H5 documentation about String in HDF5.
http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html